# Is there a way to do assertions for texts in spec level in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Cypress is really a cool tool and the below thing is stopping me from migrating scripts from protractor to cypress..

```
this.getBreadcrumText = async (value) => {
  const a = await cy.xpath("//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]")
    .text().then(txt => {
      expect(txt).equal('Dashboards')
     });       
  cy.log('------', a)
}`
```

In the above method I was able to expect the text within the page. If I want to do assertions in the spec level I should be able to return the value of a to the spec file where this function is called, which is currently not happening. Ideally in the test/spec file we should not be using the element references also.

Basically in spec file if I use

```
expect( dashboardPage.getBreadcrumText()).equal('Dashboards')
```

it is not working. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress is queue-based which means you have to return things via a `.then()` callback, similar to promises.

So

**Page object**

```js
this.getBreadcrumText = () => { 
  // returns a command chainer from which you can access text via .then()
  return cy.xpath("//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]")
    .text();
}
```

**Test**

```js
dashboardPage.getBreadcrumText()
  .then(text => {
    expect(text).equal('Dashboards')
  })
```

or, fire the assertion inside the page object using value passed in

**Page object**

```js
this.getBreadcrumText = (value) => { 
  cy.xpath("//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]")
    .invoke('text')
    .should('eq', value);
}
```

**Test**

```js
dashboardPage.getBreadcrumText('Dashboards');
```

I'm not sure all the selectors here are kosher, if any problems try those given by @RosenMihaylov

Answer (score 0):

The first important part is - async/await can not be used directly in cypress.

For asserting text I use [this plugin](https://github.com/Lakitna/cypress-commands) and here I present you a simple tmplate for text assertions:

```
cy.xpath("//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]")
    .text()
    .should('eq', 'Dashboards')
```

Also you can use [JQ .text](https://api.jquery.com/text/) where you need to use should instead of then, because it retryes for a few seconds for the expected result:

```
cy.xpath("//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]")
   .should(element =>{  
       expect(Cypress.$(element).text()).to.equal('Dashboards')
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i would like to eliminate the usage of elements (//*[contains(@data-testid,'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards')]) in the spec files and hence this question . I am already using cypress-commands npm package and thats why .text() i am able to use . In both above case you are using the element directly in the spec/test file

Comment: cy.get('[data-testid="'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards"]`) is the way to handle such selectors may be this will help you? Also it would have been helpfull if you said in the post the plugin cypress-xpath you are using, because it is not a usual cypress sintax

Comment: Ok i guess still you are not getting my question . I get that cy.get('[data-testid="'breadcrumbs-route-Dashboards"]`) is the way of using in cypress . My actual problem is if we do this way in test file and if the locator is changed due to some reason , i have to modify in all the test files . I would like to keep the reference of the elements in page level so if i modify it in one place it reflects in all test files.

Comment: I see your point, but in my expirience - it SHOULD be that way - when something changes in the code - the test should fail, otherwise it would be a pointless test. It was the way I have been told by my seniors and what is expected from my boss. We avoid the issue most of the time by adding specific `data-qa` selectors that the development team knows not to change or tell me when they are changes - that way I do not rely on usual css selectors that are changed by others often and I place the `data-qa` selectors when needed